# identifying make of MTB alloy suspension bike with frame number AMO1021160

Tags: identify-this-bike

IDENTITY OF Mountain bike FULL SUSPENSION FRAME NUMBERED   AMO1021160

Answer (score 2):

What you could try is searching stolen bike registries with a portion of the serial number and see if any bikes are returned with similar serial numbers and that look like yours.
Here are a few registeries turned up with an Internet search:

- http://www.bikeregistry.com/stolen-bike.php
- https://bikeindex.org/stolen

Neither of these turned up any results using the first couple of digits of your serial number.

Comment: I was going to say that's a silly idea, but in reality its a brilliant idea.  Assuming the serial number was well defined, then it might just work.